# Where to set mapDateToTimestamp in Websphere server 7

Tags: java, oracle, websphere, database-connection, ojdbc

I am using ojdbc6.jar to connect Oracle 10g database. but i am getting Unparsable date error. So i searched on various oracle and found out that we have to set 
[Oracle suggestion link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm) and  [Suggestion link2](http://oracle.developer-works.com/article/5227657/Does+11.2+jdbc+driver+flag+'mapDateToTimestamp'+works+both+ways+-+In+Out+DB)

> mapDateToTimestamp = false

But nowhere they mentioned where to set this connection property in WAS 7.
I tried setting this property in JVM argument but same error.
Also i tried to set this property in Data source > Custom property.
PFB screenshots[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have Oracle 10g database, you might be using incorrect driver, since ojdbc6.jar is for Oracle 11. Test your application with 10g driver.

Comment: @Gas i tried using ojdbc14.jar but got same error.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I resolved by using latest version of ojdbc14.jar.
Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"
Earlier i was using jar with Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.1.0". Application is working fine. But now i am trying to run same application and database with WAS8.5 and i am using ojdbc6.jar and i am getting Unparsable date error so still I would like to know where to set Connection properties in WAS 8.5.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled upon the same issue. To set the `oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false` property you have to define it in the ***custom properties*** of the DataSource as a key-value pair in the `connectionProperties` property. I tested it on Websphere 9.0.5.4 and Oracle 19c (Driver 19.3.0.0.0), but I believe it should also resolve the issue in the version you are working with.

[image: Configuration]